# UEFI Boot not recognizing fresh Ubuntu Install from USB Stick

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi, grub-legacy

I've been reading through several forums to try and figure out how to get a fresh Ubuntu LTS install to be recognized on an HP desktop computer.  The SSD is a NVMe.M2 hard drive. Basically I boot from a Bootable USB stick imaged on my Windows 10 PC to install the latest ver. of Ubuntu LTS.  I have completed this process successfully two other times on similar HP Desktops. But this next HP system is a bit newer.

I opted to erase the Windows 10 Home installs and have a machine dedicated to Ubuntu.   For this particular machine when trying to install Ubuntu, I successfully get through the install to the point of removing the USB and rebooting the system.   Up to this point, the USB Ubuntu install recognized the SSD and had no errors installing.  But once I reboot I get, "ERROR: No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed."

From here I have been reading about possible problems.  One find most common is the BIOS settings regarding UEFI vs. LEGACY; Secure Boot, CSM, TPM, etc.  I have tried every variation of enabling LEGACY, disabling LEGACY, enable Secure Boot, disable Secure Boot, etc. I've tried loading bios boot selector to manually find the SSD HDD and ubuntu EFI; the SSD does not show up in the boot selector.  I've reorganized the boot order.  I've tried changing the boot partition type on the Ubuntu install. No success there.  I cannot figure out why the BIOS does not recognize the SSD after the install, but recognizes it during the install.  I can even manually change partitions etc.   I've tried to understand better what's going on with UEFI vs. LEGACY installs etc.  I can't figure this part out. If I need to install Ubuntu in some type of LEGACY mode to get the PC to see it.   That doesn't make sense to me because the PC is newer and should be able to work with a UEFI mode install.   Either way I'm running in circles and need somebody with bigger understanding to point me in the right direction.

The computer has HP's ERICA2 model motherboard in it with a RYZEN 5 CPU so it's not that old.  Any help or criticism would be welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You weren't specific as to which Ubuntu LTS ISO you were trying to install... Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? 20.04? 20.04.1? 20.04.2? 20.04.3? etc..   Please be precise with details (and you'll often have more luck with newer ISOs; did you try 21.10 ?  as the *focal* media with that stack may do better..)

Comment: Many with HP have needed UEFI firmware update & SSD firmware update. Some very new HP, a user posted the only way he could install was to an external drive. If UEFI, you must have ESP - efi system partiition (FAT32), but if Legacy/BIOS/CSM, you need a 1MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag for grub to install. You can have both partitions, but only last grub install either BIOS or UEFI will work. What model HP? Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Here is the Ubuntu LTS  information:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

The HP is model: M01-F0033w

Comment: @Guiverc,. Would 21.10 give me a different type install?   I feel like I'm having issues with the cmos and way it's installed not the version.

Comment: From the EFI menu (some key at powerup to allow you to choose boot device or OS), can you select the device (as opposed to the "ubuntu" choice)?  The grub install puts two copies of the bootloaders into the EFI, one at EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi (or shimx64.efi) and one named EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi (for the device).  HP may do non-UEFI things like filter on names and only boot bootmgfw.efi (the Windows bootloader name), but the device name is standard and might work.

Comment: You still didn't say if using Ubuntu Server or Desktop; Ubuntu 20.04.3 uses the GA stack by default for Server, but HWE or specifically the  kernel stack from 21.04 for 20.04.3 (20.10 stack for 20.04.2 etc); the 21.10 stack is used by Ubuntu 20.04.4 desktop was the point of my comment; but I'd read other responses.

Comment: @Guiverc. Sorry this is a Desktop version.

Comment: @ubfan1, the device IS NOT available in the choose UEFI boot device,  but the SSD device IS available  under the Legacy boot device menu. The menu shows both these UEFI+Legacy options in the same menu.  When I select the device under Legacy boot device menu I get the same error no disk post.   As far as I know the USB install is loading via UEFI boot, this is where I don't understand this portion fully.   If the USB boots in UEFI then I'm guessing I get a UEFI boot install of Ubuntu?    So why is the SSD not showing up in the UEFI boot devices? & why is SSD in the Legacy but not booting?

Comment: @oldfred,  When I create the 1MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag, what is the process to install Ubuntu? Do I just proceed with installing from the USB at that point like I did before? Or do I have to create another partition and follow different steps?   Or is there something I'm thinking out of turn here?  Sorry I'm a little slow on this.   Here's a tutorial on creating the partition you speak of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lk6mvVU7GOU

Comment: When still using BIOS, but planning UEFI, I added both ESP & bios_grub to every drive, Now only UEFI for years I only have one drive with bios_grub for test installs in very old laptop. how you boot install media from UEFI boot menu is then how it installs. Then UEFI settings determine how install will boot. Install choice & default boot mode must match. Did you update UEFI & SSD firmware. Many with HP said they needed that. Some also found newer version worked. HP users also could only change boot order from within UEFI settings, not efibootmgr like everyone else (and grub install).

Comment: This reads very much to be a machine problem, not an Ubuntu problem.  Have you contacted HP support?  Have you an optical drive? If yes, you should boot from a DVD.  Is uefi supported on your machine?
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/check-if-uefi-or-bios

Comment: @rob grune.  At our advice I found a DVD drive to put in the machine and installed via  a DVD I burned with the same ISO.  This solved the problem.  I appreciate the help all you have provided in troubleshooting this.  I don't know what made it different with installing via DVD vs. USB but it worked.  Thank you thank you.  Just to complete the conversation yes the machine does have UEFI suppot; this is confirmed in the BIOS and in the BOOT Device menu.  Also I confirmed UEFI boot from the terminal line with the "test' command.